# Trying to perform Quantum Phase Estimation on T-gate

Tags: qiskit, simulation, quantum-fourier-transform, quantum-phase-estimation, quirk

I'm trying to perform QPE on the T-gate in [Quirk](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22X%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,1,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D,%5B1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D,%5B1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D,%5B1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D,%5B1,1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22Z%5E%C2%BC%22%5D,%5B%22Swap%22,1,%22Swap%22%5D,%5B%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%7Egf1o%22%5D,%5B1,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22,1,%22%7E16c9%22%5D,%5B1,%22%E2%80%A2%22,%22%7Egf1o%22%5D,%5B1,1,%22H%22%5D%5D,%22gates%22:%5B%7B%22id%22:%22%7Egf1o%22,%22name%22:%22U(-pi/4)%22,%22matrix%22:%22%7B%7B1,0%7D,%7B0,%E2%88%9A%C2%BD-%E2%88%9A%C2%BDi%7D%7D%22%7D,%7B%22id%22:%22%7E16c9%22,%22name%22:%22U(-pi/2)%22,%22matrix%22:%22%7B%7B1,0%7D,%7B0,-i%7D%7D%22%7D%5D%7D) but I'm not getting the correct result. For the T-gate, I should be measuring (001) with 100% probability, but instead, I'm getting the following:

[image]

I've modeled my implementation directly from the [Qiskit QPE tutorial](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/quantum-phase-estimation.html). For the unitary I am using $U(\lambda) = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & e^{i \lambda}\end{bmatrix}$.

Where did I go wrong here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The angle should get smaller. not bigger, for the controlled gates on further-apart qubits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is really close - on the website, here's the diagram that they used:
[image: circuit]

So, I think you reversed the angles - it should be $-\pi/2, -\pi/4, -\pi/2$. (Also: there's a QFT inverse that Quirk has, so you can verify that the first half of your circuit is correct).